# Copy system files in rooted android device

Tags: java, android, root

I want to copy files and directories from /root directory to a different folder inside the SD_CARD. So, I did lots of search, but couldn't found a useful answer.

I executed su command like this:

```
Process pp  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cp "+originDir+"  "+targetDir);
```

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have root on your android device. If you don't have root, you won't be able to access that directory. Then follow [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android) to see the proper way of executing commands as root

Comment: now it showing ' java.io.IOException: Broken pipe:'

Comment: Not every rooted device has the `cp` command installed. Usually you need BusyBox for the `cp` command. Furthermore you should read the cp documentation/SO for copying directories. E.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922562/how-do-i-copy-folder-with-files-to-another-folder-in-unix-linux).

Comment: is it not possible without BusyBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using `RootTools library` for android.
(RootTools: a library to run commands as root).

RootTools provides rooted developers a standardized `set of tools` for use in the development of `rooted applications`.

You can find the latest release here: https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/releases

You can find more informaiton on our wiki: https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/wiki

For a more slimmed down library, check out RootShell:
https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Priya Jagtap. This helped me