# Copy specific files from one folder to another in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, file, copy

I want to do a very similar thing than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922562/how-do-i-copy-folder-with-files-to-another-folder-in-unix-linux). The difference is that I want to copy only the files containing specific string in their name (e.g. file_00).

Using the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328988/find-all-files-with-name-containing-string), I tried this :

```
cp -a /home/folder_1/. find . -name "*file_00*" - print /home/folder_2
```

But the function cp doesn't recognize the function `find`. Then I tried

```
cp -a /home/yanncochet/folder_1/. -e'file_00' /home/yanncochet/folder_2
```

But same error message. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

`find` is a separate program from `cp`. What I think you were trying to do was use find as input for cp. You can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) for that:

```
cp $(find directory/ -name "*file_00*") destination/
```

`$(...)` basically runs the command inside and returns it's output.