# How to force 'cp' to overwrite directory instead of creating another one inside?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, cp

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will overwrite an existing directory. I have a directory `foo/` and I am trying to overwrite `bar/` with it. But when I do this:

```
cp -Rf foo/ bar/
```

a new `bar/foo/` directory is created. I don't want that. There are two files in `foo/`; `a` and `b`. There are files with same names in `bar/` as well. I want the `foo/a` and `foo/b` to replace `bar/a` and `bar/b`.

Answer (score 188):

You can do this using `-T` option in `cp`.
See Man page for `cp`.

```
-T, --no-target-directory
    treat DEST as a normal file
```

So as per your example, following is the file structure.

```
$ tree test
test
|-- bar
|   |-- a
|   `-- b
`-- foo
    |-- a
    `-- b
2 directories, 4 files
```

You can see the clear difference when you use `-v` for Verbose.
When you use just `-R` option.

```
$ cp -Rv foo/ bar/
`foo/' -> `bar/foo'
`foo/b' -> `bar/foo/b'
`foo/a' -> `bar/foo/a'
 $ tree
 |-- bar
 |   |-- a
 |   |-- b
 |   `-- foo
 |       |-- a
 |       `-- b
 `-- foo
     |-- a
     `-- b
3 directories, 6 files
```

When you use the option `-T` it overwrites the contents, **treating the destination like a normal file and not directory**.

```
$ cp -TRv foo/ bar/
`foo/b' -> `bar/b'
`foo/a' -> `bar/a'

$ tree
|-- bar
|   |-- a
|   `-- b
`-- foo
    |-- a
    `-- b
2 directories, 4 files
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: just in case anyone is tripped up by this it won't work with OSX cp https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: It's not clear that this answer is what the OP is looking for, although the examples given above mask the problem... With the -T option, files that are in an existing target (`bar/`) but *not* in the source (`foo/`) will be left in place, so this is not what most people would consider a complete overwrite of the directory. 

ie. if `bar/baz` existed already, it would still exist afterwards...

Comment: Is there no option to clean target folder in the process? I can't believe it!

Comment: This answer does answer the op question, but doesn't address the case of if the destination already exists and you want to remove contents it contains but the source directory does not.  This is not an expected behavior of copying files from one place to the other.  It only overwrites in the target things that are also in the source, it doesn't touch anything in the target that is not in the source.  You can clean the target folder by prepending a command to do it: `rm -rf bar/* && cp -TRv foo/ bar/`

Comment: I'm not a mind reader...I don't see further clarification what the OP was looking for, but this was DEFINITELY the answer that I (MEEEE) was looking for

Comment: just in case anyone is tripped up by why the link in the most upvoted comment is not working, here it is: https://web.archive.org/web/20170909193852/https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: -T is a gnuism.  I believe the BSDism is to put a slash / after the src directory. I'm not sure where MacOS gets its convention or what the relevant standards have to say, but it seems to follow BSD here.

Answer (score 116):

If you want to ensure `bar/` ends up identical to `foo/`, use `rsync` instead:

```
rsync -a --delete foo/ bar/
```

If just a few things have changed, this will execute much faster than removing and re-copying the whole directory.

- `-a` is 'archive mode', which copies faithfully files in `foo/` to `bar/`
- `--delete` removes extra files not in `foo/` from `bar/` as well, ensuring `bar/` ends up identical
- If you want to see what it's doing, add `-vh` for verbose and human-readable
- Note: the slash after `foo` is required, otherwise `rsync` will copy `foo/` to `bar/foo/` rather than overwriting `bar/` itself.

  - (Slashes after directories in rsync are confusing; if you're interested, here's the scoop. They tell rsync to refer to the *contents* of the directory, rather than the directory *itself*. So to overwrite from the *contents* of `foo/` onto the contents of `bar/`, we use a slash on both. It's confusing because it won't work as expected with a slash on *neither*, though; rsync sneakily always interprets the destination path as though it has a slash, even though it honors an absence of a slash on the source path. So we need a slash on the source path to make it match the auto-added slash on the destination path, if we want to copy the *contents* of `foo/` into `bar/`, rather than the directory `foo/` itself landing into `bar/` as `bar/foo`.)

`rsync` is very powerful and useful, if you're curious look around for what else it can do (such as copying over ssh).

Comment: Like this answer better than the `cp -T` option because it also works on macosx 

Comment: @Tom Is the end result same as the answer given below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698290/3503228

Answer (score 84):

Do it in two steps.

```
rm -r bar/
cp -r foo/ bar/
```

Comment: This is actually the **only** example given so far that will ensure that `bar` is identical in content to `foo`, not a combination of items from `foo` plus other items that may have already existed in `bar`. The highly upvoted answer from @Saurabh Meshram below has this problem.

Comment: Be extra careful using this, as it *will* remove all files from bar, even hidden ones.

Comment: mac osx:

```rm -rf bar/;
cp -r foo/ !$```

Comment: This isn't always viable...or desired...imagine if `foo` and `bar` are large directories...maybe there are files in `bar` that are not in `foo` that you don't want to remove. This shouldn't be considered a realistic answer imho

Comment: Although worked for me, but not the best solution since there might be file included in foo/ but not in bar/ which will be deleted after doing this.

Comment: @robo and also the rsync answer now

Comment: @Jonathan Is the end result same as the answer given above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349667/3503228

Comment: @Porcupine The names and contents of the files should be the same, but I think that the permissions and owners will be different between the cp and rsync methods. The timestamps may also be different.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler So, which one of rsync and cp, you think, does a better job in preserving those attributes?

Comment: @Porcupine rsync

Answer (score 30):

Use this `cp` command:

```
cp -Rf foo/* bar/
```

Comment: This doesn't remove files that are present in bar but not in foo.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by that. Why should `cp` command be removing file from source?

Comment: My understanding was that when you 'overwrite an existing directory' with another one, at the end the overwritten directory should be a copy of the other one.
I.e. at the end bar should be a copy of foo, as it is the case with @jonathan-wheeler answer but if you had a file bar/c and no foo/c then bar/c doesn't get deleted.
On a side note, I've just noticed that it's not the case with Saurabh Meshram's answer either.

Comment: Maybe we don't agree on what overwrite means, for me it's basically replace, while you might meant megre ? It's hard to tell what OP wants exactly because she only mentionned 2 files that are both in foo and bar.

Comment: This syntax also ignores hidden dot files. A large number can also blow up the glob.

Comment: That can be controlled using `shopt`

Answer (score 18):

The following command ensures dotfiles (hidden files) are included in the copy:

```
$ cp -Rf foo/. bar
```

Comment: Is this true? Looks unusual.

Comment: @Mateng I just tested it - yes it is true.

Comment: `.` means all the files in the directory. So, naturally the hidden files would be included.

Comment: That's pretty neat actually. You can also do "cp -RTf foo bar" on Linux.

Comment: . (dot) just means the current directory, no?

Comment: Together with `-a` or `-p` this also makes sure that the target directory receives the metadata (owers, permissions) of the source directory -- very nice!

Comment: See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409225/67771) for an explanation on why this works

Answer (score 7):

Very similar to @Jonathan Wheeler:

If you do not want to remember, but not rewrite `bar`:

```
rm -r bar/
cp -r foo/ !$
```

`!$` displays the last argument of your previous command.

Comment: The tip about the !$ is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

this should solve your problem.

```
\cp -rf foo/* bar/
```

Comment: The same answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698218/4175647

Answer (score 0):

In case you're in **Git Bash for Windows**:

`robocopy path/to/source path/to/target -MIR`

`-MIR` means mirror, it'll result in two identical folders. Existing files will be skipped, extra files will be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

The operation you defined is a "merge" and you cannot do that with `cp`. However, if you are not looking for merging and ok to lose the folder `bar` then you can simply `rm -rf bar` to delete the folder and then `mv foo bar` to rename it. This will not take any time as both operations are done by file pointers, not file contents.

Answer (score -6):

Try to use this command:

```
cp -Rf foo/* bar/
```