# Copying directories to a server and deleting all unnecessary files

Tags: rsync, scp, cp

When copying websites to my server, I noticed that files I had deleted in my local environment were still present on the server after the `rsync` or `scp`.

I did some research and found this question which thoroughly explains my problem; though unfortunately only provides a solution for the `cp` command.

[How to force cp to overwrite directory instead of creating another one inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698183/how-to-force-cp-to-overwrite-directory-instead-of-creating-another-one-inside#)

How can I use the same functionality of `cp -T` when copying directories from my local machine to my production server.

note: I understand git push would solve this problem, but I am looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Did you try `rsync --delete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync --delete` is the trick.

Thanks to Gordon Davisson and his comment.